# Tortoise svn repo browser too slow

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Tortoise SVN 1.9.5 repo browser is very slow if parent contains large # of projects(more than 10 mins). For other URL with the same repository where parent has few # of directory, it works. I do not see slowness with version tortoise svn 1.6.

Comment: We have the same issue, especially when the repository is deep and you want to browse starting from a deep folder. Generally, if we browse from the root it is fine. It seems that TortoiseSVN is calling the "list" command for every level in order to build the folder tree in the left panel.